# Web components messed up when Configuring Web Deploy using Win Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to google solution on this but quick answer will be appreciated. I am kind of new to this: I configured webdeploy (website) using IIS7 on Win Sever 2008. But my status bar and gridview is shows messed up. Gridview columns are in one row and status bar is on next line. What can I do to make things right? I am using IE browser.
Will this link help: http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy
I guess my CSS is getting messed up but it runs perfect on visual studio!
Thank you very much for answers!

Comment: How in the world do you expect anyone to help you? You've given no useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Under "Compatibility View Settings", the "Display Intranet Sites In Compatibility View" checkbox was checked... I unchecked was able to toggle compatibility view from the IE toolbar and everything looks great! For CSS to work perfectly: Do this!